# Custom class does not show in attributes inspector

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

When using storyboard, I usually set the Custom Class in Identity Inspector to be the class of my views and view controllers. This time, I created a base class that inherits from `UIPageViewController` (`PageViewController`) and then two other classes (`ProfilePageViewController`, and `ContextPageViewController`) that in turn inherit from `PageViewController`.

The idea is for `PageViewController` to extend the functionality of `UIPageViewController` by providing mechanisms that will be common to both `ProfilePageViewController` and `ContextPageViewController`. So far so good.

Then I drag a couple of view controllers to the interface builder and set the classes I wrote before as Custom Class (again, that's `ProfilePageViewController`, and `ContextPageViewController`).

If I had used a `UIPageViewController` from scratch instead, the Properties Inspector would look something like this:

[image]

But it doesn't.

One other thing. I know that if I drag a `UIPageViewController` and *then* change the custom class, this will show properly. However, both `ProfilePageViewController` and `ContextPageViewController` are inside Container Views, which pretty much means that Xcode generated them automatically. That is:

1. I create a parent view controller
2. Drag two container views into it
3. Xcode generates two `UIViewController`s automatically
4. I want these two view controllers to be of a custom class which is a subtype of `UIPageViewController`.

What the attributes inspector shows, instead, is just the properties for view controllers:

[image]

How can I make these properties show?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out! It's almost as if the universe was expecting that I would post here before showing me the way :P see my answer; it's actually quite simple.

Comment: Glad you found something that worked. I thought your question was asking about something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent quite some time and effort trying to do this, and it turns out that it's quite simple.

1. Drag a Page View Controller onto the canvas;
2. Change it's custom class property;
3. Control + drag from the container to the new controller;
4. Click "embed".

Xcode will automatically replace the controller that it generated automatically. You can delete that.